# Non-String Top Trumps card game error

Tags: python

```
import random
from random import shuffle
import time

game = True
while game:

    class X(object): # creates an object based class named X
        def __init__(self, name, rating, power, defence, XRay, toughness): #defines the structures of the class so they can be later displayed
            self.name = name
            self.rating = rating
            self.power = power
            self.defence = defence            
            self.XRay = XRay
            self.toughness = toughness

        def __repr__(self):
            print("\nName : ", self.name, "\nRating : ", self.rating, "\nPower : ", self.power, "\nDefence : ", self.defence, "\nXRay : ", self.XRay, "\nToughness : ", self.toughness) #Telling the code that whenever it calles out the X class to print the atributes of the Card

    q = X("Inferno Scorpion", 3, 970, 940, 2010, 1090)
    w = X("Grandmaster Sub-Zero", 3, 900, 1000, 1900, 1000)
    e = X("Kenshi", 3, 910, 930, 1840, 950)
    r = X("Master Of Souls Ermac", 3, 940, 850, 1790, 950)
    t = X("Sun God Kotal Kahn", 3, 930, 950, 1040, 890)
    y = X("Jax Briggs", 2, 500, 520, 1020, 800)
    u = X("Cassie Cage", 2, 520, 380, 900, 400)
    i = X("Sonya Blade", 2, 460, 370, 830, 380)
    i2 = X("Tactical Sonya Blade", 3, 930, 840, 1770, 930)
    o = X("D'vorah", 2, 460, 390, 850, 370)
    p = X("Kung Jin", 2, 410, 360, 770, 330)
    p2 = X("Bojutsu Kung Jin", 3, 860,  880, 1740, 930)
    a = X("Sergent", 1,  210, 230, 440, 230)
    s = X("Oni", 1, 250, 260, 510, 200)
    d = X("Monk", 1, 230, 210, 440, 200 )
    f = X("Osh-Tekk", 1, 220, 220, 440, 200)
    g = X("Trooper", 1, 200, 200, 400, 210)
    j = X("Kano", 2, 400, 380, 780, 420)
    k = X("Shirai Ryu", 1, 220, 180, 400, 200)
    l = X("Reptile", 3, 780, 760, 1540, 890)
    z = X("Johnny Cage", 2, 390, 420, 810, 360)
    x = X("Lin Kuei", 1, 180, 220, 400, 200)
    c = X("Saurian", 1, 210, 190, 400, 200) # the playing cards


    allCards = [q, w, e, r, t, y, u, i, o, p, a, s, d, f, g, j, k, l, z, x, c]

    shuffle (allCards)

    print ("Your deck is being dealt... please wait") 
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("...")
    time.sleep(1)


    half = int(len(allCards)/2)
    p1 = (allCards[0:half])
    cpu = (allCards[half:])

    print ("\nPlayer one has",len(p1), "cards... let's do this!")

    def error():
        global p1
        global cpu        
        chosenability()

    def chosenability ():
        global p1
        global cpu

        pick=input("\nMake your selection: \n")
        user_choice=pick.lower()

        if user_choice=="Rating":
            p1_choice=p1[0].rating
            cpu_choice=cpu[0].rating
            print ("\nRating = ", p1_choice)
        elif user_choice=="Power":
            p1_choice=p1[0].power
            cpu_choice=cpu[0].power
            print ("\nPower = ", p1_choice)
        elif user_choice=="Defence":
            p1_choice=p1[0].defence
            cpu_choice=cpu[0].defence
            print ("\nDefence = ", p1_choice)
        elif user_choice=="XRay":
            p1_choice=p1[0].XRay
            cpu_choice=cpu[0].XRay
            print ("\nXRay = ", p1_choice)
        else:
            print ("\nInvalid selection")
            error()

        if p1_choice>cpu_choice:
            time.sleep(2)
            print ("Computers card is...",(cpu[0]))
            time.sleep(2)             
            print ("\nYou win card", cpu[0].name)
            p1.append(cpu[0])
            del cpu[0]
            p1=p1+[p1.pop(0)]
            print ("You now have", len(p1),"cards")
            print ("CPU now has", len(cpu),"cards")

        elif p1_choice<cpu_choice:                
            time.sleep(2)
            print ("Computers card is...",(cpu[0]))
            time.sleep(2)
            print ("\nYou Lose your card", p1[0].name)
            cpu.append(p1[0])
            del p1[0]
            cpu=cpu+[cpu.pop(0)]
            print ("CPU now has", len(cpu),"cards")
            print ("You now have", len(p1),"cards")

        else:                
            time.sleep(2)
            print ("Computers card is...",(cpu[0]))
            time.sleep(2)
            print ("\nDraw")
            cpu=cpu+[cpu.pop(0)]
            p1=p1+[p1.pop(0)]


    while len(p1)>0 and len(cpu)>0:

        time.sleep(0.5)
        print ("\nYour card is \n", (p1[0]))
        time.sleep(1.5)

        chosenability()


    print ("Play again ?")
    play_again = input ("Type yes, or no: ")
    if play_again == "Yes" or play_again == "YES" or play_again == "yes":
        game = True
```

Output

```
Your deck is being dealt... please wait
...

Player one has 10 cards... let's do this!

Your card is 

Name :  Cassie Cage 
Rating :  2 
Power :  520 
Defence :  380 
XRay :  900 
Toughness :  400
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\GCSE Computer Sciance\Practicle\XMain.py", line 127, in <module>
builtins.TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

When I run the code it returns this error, could someone help me fix it?

Comment: Could you edit your question to give a summary of what you're trying to achieve? It's very sparse, and the reader has to go through all of your code first. What have you tried? Describe things a little more!

Comment: Also, I'd say unrelatedly that `X` is a terrible name for a class (not at all descriptive!) and I'd define each card inside the array to avoid more single character variables. When this code works (*and not before*) you might benefit from codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Pureferret is right. Other things you should do is to move the class definition and the functions out of the loop and try to rewrite the code to not use `globals`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `__repr__` method must return a string object, but you don't return anything:

```
    def __repr__(self):
        print("\nName : ", self.name, "\nRating : ", self.rating, "\nPower : ", self.power, "\nDefence : ", self.defence, "\nXRay : ", self.XRay, "\nToughness : ", self.toughness)
```

When you use `print ("\nYour card is \n", (p1[0]))` the `p1[0]` card is converted to a string by `print()`, which means that `p1[0].__str__()` is called; since you did not define that method Python then falls back to `p1[0].__repr__()`, which returned `None` and resulted in the error.

Don't use `print()` here, use `return`:

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return "\nName : {}\nRating : {}\nPower : {}\nDefence : {}\nXRay : {}\nToughness : {}".format(
            self.name, self.rating, self.power, self.defence, self.XRay, self.toughness)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say without running your code, but it could be that you never return a string for the `__repr__` method, but just print it out.

Return what you print, and call print on the string instead.